# Typing in TextField moves cursor to end (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In macOS Ventura 13.0.1 and Xcode 14.1, I'm experiencing an issue where when I type in the beginning of a `TextField`, the cursor for some reason moves to the back.

I was able to reproduce it very simply:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "DEFG"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            VStack {
                TextField("Text", text: $text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## To reproduce:

1. Open the app, and move the cursor to the start of the `TextField`. (so the insertion point is before the "D".
2. Type a letter, like "A", and the insertion point should jump to the end for some reason.

I have determined the cause is the `VStack`. For some reason, removing it fixes this issue entirely. However, in my real app, I do need the `VStack` as I have other elements too.

I wonder what's going on here. Is there some major oversight I have made? Or could this be an issue with `SwiftUI`?

If anyone is having trouble reproducing, I can upload a video.

Comment: Sadly, TextField on macOS in SwiftUI has always been plagued with issues. I’ve always had to wrap NSTextField instead

Comment: @jnpdx Darn. I would think such a simple example would just work, but it doesn't seem to. Could there be something I maybe missed?

Comment: If I remove the NavigationSplitView but keep the VStack the problem goes away so maybe this is more related to NavigationSplitView in combination with TextField.

Comment: I am seeing the same bug on Ventura 13.5.1 with a single `TextField` placed inside a sheet. No `VStack` or other view besides `TextField` is necessary to reproduce the bug.